# How can I calculate a Total Value When You Know the Amount of the Percent

Tags: excel-formula

How can I calculate a value total when I know the percentage of a total amount. for example: need to raise 50,000. Potential fund 1 has funded 25% of the 50,000. Potential fund 2 has funded 25%.

This goes down the table and at the bottom of Potential fund 1's column I need to know the total value due based on the respective percentages.

I have tried some basic formulas but nothing is giving me the correct output

```
Total Req'd     potential fund 1     potential fund 2  Acquired
£50,000                25%                 25%         £25,000.00
£7,000                 100%                0%          £7,000.00
£1,000                 65%                 21%         £860.00
£250,000               5%                  5%          £25,000.00
£314,000                                               £57,860.00
```

So basically for Potential fund 1 I need to know in line with the percentage amounts detailed what there total amount would be in a currency value.

If anyone can help that would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the currently acquired amount you could use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:C2)*A2)
```

Put the formula in `D2` and pull down.

[image]

If you want the amount in column `A`, you could use

```
=D2/SUM(B2:C2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking to calculate the current obligation amount based on percentage against the total required for Potential funder 1 and funder 2.I have an acquired calculation running but this it to identify against the percentages specified what that total amount works out at. if you can help with that, thanks!

Comment: You can still use `SUMPRODUCT` but in `B6` use: `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5*B2:B5)` and in `C6` use: `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5*C2:C5)`

Comment: You are a legend thank you so much thats got it! :D